# /tmp used 100% where is files?

Tags: linux, centos, mount, tmp

On Centos 6.3 server I noticed that /tmp has no longer free space to store files.

```
[root@]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_root
                       99G   11G   84G  12% /
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             194M   65M  120M  35% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg0-lv_tmp
                       97M   92M  704K 100% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg1-lv0    50G  180M   47G   1% /mnt/ssd2
```

But there is nothing in /tmp at all

```
[root@]# ls -Sahl /tmp |more
total 10K
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root root 4.0K Mar 16 04:29 ..
drwxrwxrwt.  3 root root 3.0K Mar 16 03:32 .
drwx------.  2 root root 1.0K Mar 16 04:28 mc-root
```

My question is: How could it be? By what /tmp mount space used? And how could I clean it?

Comment: df -h is telling you Used=0 ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `lsof /tmp` to see currently opened file.

If you delete a file, while a software still have a lock on it, you won't see it anymore, but it will still have hd space assigned to it.

Comment: All /tmp space used by so many threats like: php-fpm 2186 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4

Comment: I have server with nginx+php-fpm+apc so it looks line the /tmp partition is not enough space at all...

Comment: I've found apc.ini this line: ; The mktemp-style file_mask to pass to the mmap module.
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
i think change this line to /var/tmp/apc.XXXXXX???

Comment: When you check the LSOF result, the 'DEL' give you an idea of which file now only exist in memory. Restarting your software stack (ie: nginx, php, etc.) should clear the HD space issues. 

And you are right, 100MB is not enough

Comment: An [alternative command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18616) to `lsof /tmp` is the command `fuser -vm /tmp`.

Answer (score 3):

That's a very small /tmp partition.

Show the output of `lsof /tmp` to see which processes have open files there. Stopping the relevant process should free the space.

Comment: <pre>[root@]# lsof /tmp
COMMAND  PID  USER  FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
php-fpm 2185  root DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2186 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2187 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2188 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2189 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2190 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
php-fpm 2253 nginx DEL    REG  253,3            12 /tmp/apc.7mboJ4
...
</pre>